# How to fix div position at the bottom without covering other div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs, one is accordion, second one is blue box.

I need to place blue box at the bottom of the page, so position: fixed + bottom: 0; work fine, until accordion gets bigger. When accordion number of items gets huge, blue box covers the accordion, so it becomes impossible to use it.

How can i place blue box at the bottom of page without covering accordion

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <div>First div - accordion</div>
  
  <div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0">Second div - blue box</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Image how it looks with one item in accordion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hP93D.png)

[Image how it covers accordion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4oHX.png)

[Image how it suppose to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSA5M.png)

Comment: Add a large enough amount of padding-bottom to the body, so that there is free space below the accordions ...

Comment: @CBroe if I add padding-bottom to accordion div or body, it would work for 1 accordion item like fixed position and bottom: 0.
If there are more than one item, space between accordion and blue box would stay the same. I mean accordion would fill full page, then you have to scroll this padding-bottom space and see blue box. I don't want to have this free space when accordion filled full page

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about there. You either provide enough space at the page bottom, so that the whole content can be scrolled so far, that the footer doesn't overlap the lowest position of the accordion (whether in opened or collapsed state, doesn't matter) - or you don't ... Not sure where you imagine there to be any alternatives to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flexbox is a solution

```
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

main {
  flex: 1
}

header {
  background-color: silver;
}

main {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

footer {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>HEADING....</header>
  <main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita ullam aut veritatis sint similique saepe, molestiae doloremque assumenda nobis deleniti praesentium explicabo, quae iste tempora! Fuga facere autem dolorem cum?</p>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>Footer area</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewport to solve this, try following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="accordion-div">First div - accordion</div>

    <div class="second-div">Second div - blue box</div>
  </body>
  <style>
    .accordion-div {
      width: 100%;
      height: 90vh;
      overflow: hidden;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }
    .second-div {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 0;
    }
  </style>
</html>
```

Here I have set the viewport for the first div to 90vh, but you might need to use a slightly different value to fit to your application. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Unfortunately, it doesn’t help me. I suppose, I'm bad at explanation or doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

To place div at the bottom of the page when page is short and the screen is not filled and stay at the bottom without overlapping the content, when there is more than screenful of content, I added footer, placed div inside. Also, I added css to body and footer like this:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
  marging-top: auto;
}
```

Now "blue box" always stay at the bottom in both cases.